# Why this JavaScript is not dynamically creating object properties?

Tags: javascript

This code can't dynamically set object properties.  `console.log(key, val)` shows that the loop iterates correctly over the `options` (merged with `defaults` and filtered by the keys of `defaults`):

```js
function Foo(options) {
   var defaults = { foo: "bar" },
       options  = _.defaults(options || {}, defaults);

    _.each(_.pick(options, _.keys(defaults)), function(val, key) {
        this[key] = val; // Not working
    });

    this.baz = 'bar'; // Works
};

var foo = new Foo();

foo.hasOwnProperty('foo'); // false
foo.hasOwnProperty('baz'); // true
```

**Q1**: Why it's not working? Is `this[key]` wrong?

**Q2**: How (normally) one should deal with the key-sensitive problem, that is passing`{"FOO": "bar"}`?

Functions (if matters): [`._defaults`](http://underscorejs.org/#defaults), [`_.pick`](http://underscorejs.org/#pick) and [`_.keys`](http://underscorejs.org/#keys).

Comment: Learn more about how `this` works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.

Comment: Why not just `_.defaults(this, options, defaults)`?

Comment: @Bergi, I guess he wants to whitelist the settable properties to those defined in `defaults`.

Comment: @fencliff: Oops, right. However, using `keys()` and `pick()` seems to be so inefficient...

Comment: @Bergi, it's the dilemma of the computationally expensive one-liner vs. labour-intensive specialized method. The object is most likely quite small, so I'd probably just go with the one-liner myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `this` context in the `each` callback is not pointing to the containing function `Foo`. You can provide the context as the second argument to `each`:

```
_.each(_.pick(options, _.keys(defaults)), function(val, key) {
    this[key] = val;
}, this);
```

Note that you don't need to iterate over the values at all, you can just use `_.extend`:

```
_.extend(this, _.pick(options, _.keys(defaults)));
```

Comment: Stupid me for not spotting the context option. Thanks.

Comment: *"The `this` context in the each callback points to the callback function"*: No, it most likely refers to the global object, `window`. `this` would only refer to the function itself if it was explicitly set to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Every function has its own "this", so the "this" inside the _.each isn't the same that is in Foo. You need to manually pass the "this" from Foo to the each, in order to do that, you can use the underscore function _.bind.

Comment: No, only bound functions have their own "this". However, each function *call* determines the current `this` value